# Why do JSON queries return object if there is one element, list if more than one?

Tags: python, json, pymysql

I had to rewrite a python script from python2 to python 3 to solve  the encoding problems I had the easiest way. I had to move from mysqldb to pymysql which seemed to use same syntax. I accessed the pymysql's github[1] site and following examples I noticed that when query result was one element it returned a JSON object but when it returns more than one, it returns a list.

Wouldn't it be more consistent to return always a list with 0, 1 or whichever number of elements? Why is it done this way?

Note: to avoid this behavior in pymysql just remove the cursorclass parameter from:

```
# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='user',
passwd='passwd', db='db', charset='utf8mb4',
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

[1] https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to JSON API specification, this behaviour was due to a breaking change in v1.0rc1:

> BREAKING CHANGE: Singular resource objects SHOULD now be be
>   represented with JSON objects instead of arrays. This allows for
>   symmetrical representations in request and response documents, as well
>   as PUT/POST requests and PATCH operations. It also simplifies
>   implementations which do not support batch operations (i.e. they can allow an object and not an array).

You can have a look [here](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/237)